# Dynamically extract text from a userform

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, dynamic, userform

I would like to extract the text from textboxes in a userform and store them as elements in an array. However, these textboxes have dynamic names and I cannot set the array elements because it stores them as a string.

```
'Loop through the sections to fill the array using a concatonated dynamic path
For Counter = 0 To numSections - 1

    'Fill in title, start page, end page
    sectionInfo(Counter, 0) = "UserForm1.TextInput" & CStr(Counter) & ".Text"

    sectionInfo(Counter, 1) = "UserForm1.pageStart" & CStr(Counter) & ".Text"

    sectionInfo(Counter, 2) = "UserForm1.pageEnd" & CStr(Counter) & ".Text"

Next Counter
```

How can I concatenate the string and pass it as a command and not a string? I am beginning to think that this is not possible as I have looked everywhere.

Comment: Use the `Controls` collection. Something like `UserForm1.Controls("TextInput" & CStr(Counter)).Text` and so on.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much Vincent!

Comment: @VincentG, if you turn your comment into an answer, we can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Controls` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/object-model-for-microsoft-forms). Something like `UserForm1.Controls("TextInput" & CStr(Counter)).Text` and so on.

```
'Loop through the sections to fill the array using a concatonated dynamic path
For Counter = 0 To numSections - 1
    'Fill in title, start page, end page
    sectionInfo(Counter, 0) = UserForm1.Controls("TextInput" & CStr(Counter)).Text
    sectionInfo(Counter, 1) = UserForm1.Controls("pageStart" & CStr(Counter)).Text
    sectionInfo(Counter, 2) = UserForm1.Controls("pageEnd" & CStr(Counter)).Text
Next Counter
```